# Changing javascript context in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an element inside an iframe. If i search on the chrome console for example - document.querySelector(< ELEMENT >) - the element doesn't show up (returns null)

However, if i change the javascript context on the console options, and query again, the element is there.

I want to call that element from a chrome extension.. How can i reference the "document" inside that specific iframe?

The frame element example:

```
<frame name="SessionA" id="SessionA" scrolling="no" piweb_src="action=../applications/as400/emulator/help.html?IdentTab=SessionA">
```

The element i want to access example:

```
<th id="11" onblur="GeneFocusOff(this)" colspan="55" style="color:#FF00FF; ">  RANDOM TEXT </th>
```

Comment: [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) only have acess to page DOM from extension in chrome

Comment: Assuming it's a *same-origin* frame your content script can do document.querySelector('#SessionA').contentDocument.querySelector('your selector')

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes that works!! You should write that as an answer so i can mark as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

As said in wOxxOm comment if the element is on the page you can use

`document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument` or in some cases
`document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document`

using [contentDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) will get you the javascript context you want of the iframe.

Then you can get the element you want with the full

`document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument.querySelector('your selector')`

note: in cases you may get a cross-orgin frame error